# Jquery Click Buttons Show Content

Tags: php, jquery

Using Jquery,I want to show  the content on  a  element when a button is clicked.In each column there are buttons.When I click ,corresponding content should be displayed when I click on the button.

1.This is code block

```
  <html>
     <body>
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td><div><button type="button" class="addButton">
```

Show

```
       </table>
     </body>
```

2.Scripting Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".addButton").click(function(event){
       var tdCount=$("#addInf.addInfo").length;
       //length of the td elements
       alert(tdCount);
```

```
       for(var $i=0;$i<tdCount;$i++){
           alert($i);
           $(".addButton:eq(0)").hide(); 
          // $(".addButton:eq($i)").hide();
```

//not able to hide for ith elements

```
        }                                
    });     
});
```

My problem is first element is hidden.I want to dynamically show content of first column td and second columns td and so on //when a button is clicked and hide the button as well  Iam able to do for one td element hide and show content.But how to do it dynamically

Comment: Your HTML is not proper.

Comment: `Div` and `tr` is not closed .

Comment: Actually all the html is closed but Iam able to show the first td content and hide the first button.If I have to do on the fly and there are many buttons then ,how to get the different content for each button.If i click one button that content display and so on and so forth

Comment: i have perfect answer for this. See the link below [link](http://codepen.io/akhilmekkatt/pen/uhgEo)

Answer (score 0):

The context of the button click event handler is the button itself. In order to hide it you can simply do:

```
$(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic div inside each td/div and insert a class to all this dynamic divs.

[**DEMO HERE (JSFIDDLE)**](http://jsfiddle.net/don/6ym35nra/1/)

Basically you need to use `parent()` and `find()` function inside the same div.

After that, only use the `show()`